# CSS Styling inside JS Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following HTML and Javascript code. The `Randomize()` function as displayed on the bottom is contained inside of a div which has a certain themeing applied to it.

```
div id="themeing">
     <script type="text/javascript">Randomize()</script>
</div>
```

> ```
> function Randomize() {
>     var images = new Array("images/banner/banner1.jpg","images/banner/banner2.jpg","images/banner/banner3.jpg","images/banner/banner4.jpg");
>     var imageNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
>     document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[imageNum] + "')";
> }
>
> window.onload = Randomize;
> ```

This function would allow me to rotate images in the banner of my website on pageload. 
Right now the function works, but the styling, which is applied by CSS to the `id="themeing"` does not apply to the images which are being output by Javascript.

How do I make it so that the output of `Randomize()` gets styled appropriately?

Comment: What is CSS ID? Its ID property of HTML Element which CSS leverages.

Comment: Edited the Original post. Is this more clear?

Comment: Still VEry Confusing :(

Comment: Alright, give me a moment, i'll try again.

Comment: For me the functions looks ok. Could you add some more html and css to your question? I think the problem isn't shown yet. You are talking about a outer div. More information about this could be useful.

Comment: Edited again, I really hope I made myself clear this time :)

Comment: I am sorry, I think I know what you are talking about but, at least for me, I need more infmoration :D You are setting the property of the div with the ID "header" could you add this element to your html part? Maybe add the CSS of both divs, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the CHTML id you are talking about but the images can be set to cover the whole background by setting two more attributes :

```
background-repeat: no-repeat; //in case you don't want repetition of image.
 background-size: cover;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the same problem yesterday :)

I found the solution using Jquery plugin and the .css function :

```
$('jQuery selector').css({"css property name":"css property value"});
```

If you don't want to use Jquery perhaps you could look on their plug-in how they coded it?